# Separate classes into their own definition and implementation files and main in its own file

Tags: c++, function, class

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//-----------------------------------------------------------------//
//-------------------------class employee--------------------------//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------//
class Employee
{
private: string empName;
   int empNum;
   string hireDate;
public:
 Employee():empName(""),empNum(0), hireDate("") //default ctor
 {}

 Employee(string name, int num, string date)
 {
  empName = name;
  empNum = num;
  hireDate = date;
 }

 void setempName(string n);
 void setempNum(int nm);
 void setHiredate(string d);
 string getName();
 int getNum();
 string getDate();
 void print();
};

void Employee::setempName(string n)
{empName = n ;}

void Employee::setempNum(int nm)
{empNum = nm;}

void Employee::setHiredate(string d)
{hireDate = d;}

string Employee::getName()
{return empName;}

int Employee::getNum()
{return empNum;}

string Employee::getDate()
{return hireDate;}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------//
//--------------------class production worker----------------------//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------//
class ProductionWorker : public Employee
{
private:
 int shift;
 double hrlyPay;
public:
 ProductionWorker():shift(0) , hrlyPay(0.0)
 {}

 ProductionWorker(int sh , double pay)
 {
  shift = sh;
  hrlyPay = pay;
 }

 void setshift(int s);
 void setPay(double p);
 int getshift();
 double getPay();
 void print();
};

void ProductionWorker::print()
{
 cout << "Employee Name: " << getName() << endl;
 cout << "Employee Number: " << getNum() << endl;
    cout << "Hire Date: " << getDate() << endl;
    cout << "Shift: " << getshift();

 if(shift == 1)
 {
  cout << "(Day Shift)" << endl;}
 else
  cout << "(Night Shift)" << endl;

    cout << "Pay Rate: $" << getPay()<< endl;
}

void ProductionWorker::setshift(int sh) // 
{sh = shift;}

void ProductionWorker::setPay(double p)
{p = hrlyPay;}

int ProductionWorker::getshift()
{return shift;}

double ProductionWorker::getPay()
{return hrlyPay;}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------//
//-------------------------Main------------------------------------//
//-----------------------------------------------------------------//
int main()
{
 int Shift;
 double pay;
 cout << "Enter 1 for Day Shift or 2 for Night Shift: "<<endl;
 cout<< "Any deviation will default to Night Shift ";
 cin >> Shift;
 cout << "Enter hourly pay: $";
 cin >> pay;
    ProductionWorker emp1(Shift, pay);
 emp1.setempName("Pedro, Colon");
 emp1.setempNum(8675309);
 emp1.setHiredate("1-1-2000");
 emp1.print();
 return 0;
}
```

When I put everything in one main function, my code works. However, when I try to separate classes into their own definition and implementation files and main in its own file. My code does not work. Is there anything wrong with my code. Please help me I'm just the beginner of c++

Problem:
I need to separate them into 1 main function, 2 definition and 2 implementation files

Comment: you are supposed to tell us what is wrong with the code. Do you get error messages? If yes you should include them in the question

Comment: I already added the errors to my question.

Comment: you have to `#include <string>`

Comment: it still does not work

Comment: "undefined reference" is a link error. What is your build command?

Comment: I work my code on cloud 9

Answer (score 3):

Your main contains `using namespace std;`. That makes elements of the `std` namespace (such as `std::string`) available without qualification (i.e. `string`).

Your header files don't contain this, so you have to qualify the type. Please don't add the using directive to the header files; doing so is considered bad style, because you force users of your header to have all the `std` symbols in the global namespace.

As tobi mentioned in the comments, you also should include the header files you need from where you need them, e.g. in `employee.h` you have a field of type `std::string`, so you should `#include <string>` in that file.

Comment: I edited my code, and I have another problem. In the main function, it says undefined reference to `Employee::setempName(std::string), undefined reference to `Employee::setempNum(int)', .... What should I do with this error?

Comment: You're not linking the files together. When you have more than one source file, compilation gets a little more complicated. Most tutorials should explain how it works then.